# Force sed to ignore white space

Tags: xml, bash, shell, unix, sed

I am processing an XML file with sed. The content of the file to be replaced is bellow.

```
<NS1:myService>
    <NS1:code>1</NS1:code>
    <NS1:timestamp>Event_Time_Stamp</NS1:timestamp>
    <NS1:log>
        <NS1:logLevel>some_level</NS1:logLevel>
        <NS1:loggerName>log_back</NS1:loggerName>
        <NS1:message>loggable_message</NS1:message>
            <NS1:node>none</NS1:node>
            <NS1:host>my_host</NS1:host>
    </NS1:log>
</NS1:myServices>
```

I need to replace contents of the  node with the my text. It works every time when variable which contains my text has NO space. As soon as there is space sed throws an error.

> sed: -e expression #1, char 120: unterminated `s' command

Here is how I create my message in my script

```
 text="APPLICATION:\t\t$app\n"
 text=$text"RECEIVER:\t\t$receiver\n"
 text=$text"LOGGABLE MESSAGE:\t$message\n"
 text=$text"SENDER:\t\t$sender\n"
 text=$text"DATE CREATED:\t$created\n"
```

I use the following sed statement to do my replacements

```
sed -i 's|<NS1:message>.*<|<NS1:message>'$text'<|g' $workfile
```

However the above command breaks every time on space. How can I escape white space so sed would process it just like any other character?

Comment: Use an XML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Comment: If I could use XML parser I would have asked about that but I need to use sed. However thanks for trying.

Comment: @svager Why do you need to use sed?

Comment: Short answer is part of the "standard" toolkit in my company.

Comment: Just a note: he don't want **parse** the xml. He want replace some simple string in one line. The `sed` is perfectly suitable for this. Of course, xmlstarlet is perfect tool - but you don't need a hammer for pushpins... Make a difference between _parsing_ and _replacing text_ in one line...

Answer (score 2):

As soon as I posted the question I figured it out. I needed yo use **"**

Command looks like this

```
sed -i 's|<NS1:message>.*<|<NS1:message>'"$text"'<|g' $workfile
```